# MQSeries: Is syncpoint/rollback possible when getting asynchronously with MCB?

Tags: asynchronous, callback, transactions, ibm-mq

I want to pull messages off a MQS queue in a C client, and would love to do so asynchronously so I don't have to start (explicitly) multithreading. The messages will be forwarded to another system that acts "transactionally" but is completely incompatible with XA. So I'd like to have a way to explicitly commit (and thereby remove) a message that's been successfully handed off to the other system, and *not* commit if this failed, so that the last message is retained for a more successful later attempt.

I've read about the SYNCPOINT option and understand how I'd use that around a regular GET, but I haven's seen any hints on how to make asynchronous message retrieval have transactional behavior like this. Any hints, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are describing using the asynchronous callback capability, ie you register a routine to be called when a message arrives, and ask for any get to be under syncpoint... An explanation of how some of it works is in here, https://share.confex.com/share/117/webprogram/Handout/Session9513/share_advanced_mqi.pdf page 4+

Effectively you get called with the MQ message under syncpoint, do your processing with another system, then commit or rollback the message before returning.

Be aware without the use of e.g. XA 2 phase commit, there is always going to be the windows of e.g. committing to the external system and a power outage means the message under the unit of work gets rolled back inside MQ as you didnt have time to perform the commit.

Comment: Yep, I am indeed talking about CB. Pardon my sloppy language!

The PPT from your link nicely describes this, thanks!

If what you say later - that I get called with the message under SYNCPOINT in any case - is true then that's fantastic! How did you learn this? Do you happen to know of some bit of documentation which makes this explicit?

Yep, I could end up with a dupe at restart if I die before committing. Not great but not a problem, but thanks for the warning!

Comment: You provide the MQGMO options for the get used for the callback, so in this case you would want to supply a MQGMO with options including SYNCPOINT. Not sure on the docs but a quick google shows others using it (http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=365250&sid=88daa131ff4b430c454f2cd6ae04c039 for example)

Comment: THAT's the hint I needed - now it seems obvious. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: my misunderstanding, didn't realise that the application was using a callback to retrieve messages, which is indeed fully asynchronous behavior. Disregard the answer below.

Do `MQGET` with `MQGMO_SYNCPOINT`, then issue either `MQCMIT` or `MQBACK`.

"Asynchronous" and "synchronous" may be misnomers - these are your *patterns* of using MQ - whether you wait for a reply message or not, these patterns do not affect how MQ processes your calls. Transaction management (unit of work management) works across any MQI calls that use SYNCPOINT, no matter if they are part of a request/reply pattern or not.

Comment: I don't think that's true - starting in MQ 7.5, there is explicitly functionality in the API for asynchronous processing (from the point of view of the application): This involves setting up a callback function which MQI calls whenever another message becomes available. Meanwhile, the app can do whatever other processing it wants. That's exactly what "asynchronous" means: The app is not blocking while waiting for each message to arrive. IBM's example prog: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024020_.htm

Comment: Yes, you are right. What put me on a wrong track was you haven't mentioned that you were using a callback (although I should have paid more attention - you mentioned MCB in the title, meaning apparently MQCB.) And you can't imagine how many times I've heard wrong usage of "asynchronous" around MQ. Apology if I came across as condescending - didn't mean that. Marked my answer as wrong.

Comment: With all my little inaccuracies I hardly gave you a chance! Thanks for inspiring me to be more careful.